# How do I return a ListenableFuture<Result> with work manager 2.0?

Tags: android, androidx, android-workmanager

It seems ListenableWorker no longer has the @RestrictTo(RestrictTo.Scope.LIBRARY_GROUP) restriction however I can't figure out or find examples on how to properly return a ListenableFuture< Result> in my overriden startWork() function.

As far as I can tell, the only option is to return a SettableFuture.create< Result>() but that still requires suppressing the "RestrictedApi" warning/error.

Anyone know a simpler way ?

Edit: This is the way to do it as far as I've gathered which makes use of CallbackToFutureAdapter.Completer

```
override fun startWork(): ListenableFuture<Result> {
    return CallbackToFutureAdapter.getFuture({
        it.set(ListenableWorker.Result.success())
    })

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per the [Threading in ListenableWorker documentation page](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/advanced/listenableworker):

> You can create ListenableFutures one of two ways:
>
> 1. If you use Guava, use `ListeningExecutorService`.
> 2. Otherwise, include [`councurrent-futures`](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/concurrent#declaring_dependencies) in your gradle file and use [`CallbackToFutureAdapter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/concurrent/futures/CallbackToFutureAdapter.html).

Comment: There is virtualy no working example in videos or blogs on how to use ListenableWorker for use cases where you need a job to run for more than 10 mins. There is merely a mention in the developer's documentation with an incomplete sample, whose code is very hard to follow. Please, can this be addressed? @ianhanniballake

From that example, trying to adapt ait and I keep on getting a CallbackToFutureAdapter.getFuture getting garbage collected, but there is no single documentation on how to resolve the error. Also, is there support for RxJava coming soon?

Comment: @RowlandMtetezi - *any* worker can use `setForegroundAsync()`, following along with the [long running worker documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/advanced/long-running). That's the only API needed (building a Notification is a lot of work, but there's plenty of guides to that). You can always [file a documentation bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=192697) if there's specific documentation you'd like to see added.

Comment: Would really appreciate if the docs for listenable worker are updated properly to show how to use threading  using callbackfuture or any other way. As a lot of APIs in server or SDKs are now asynchronous calls